# Is 'to be waiting for me...' equal to 'were waiting for me...' in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, to-infinitive, progressive-aspect

This is a sentence I saw in my practice book.

> I don't expect them to be waiting for me.

I want to rewrite it as 'I don't expect them were waiting for me', because it is more nature for me, a non-anglophone learner from China.

But are they the same meaning? May you tell me?

Comment: No, your sentence is not correct. If you wanted to change it, you would have to write: I don't expect that they were waiting for me - or - waited for me.

Comment: @RonaldSole Can the 'that' not be omitted here definitely?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The structure in English is "expect" + direct object + to infinitive

> I expect him to play.

The to infinitive is required in this construction.  There is an alternate structure  "expect" + "that content clause". The word "him" is the direct object of "expect" and has the object form "him"

> I expect that he will play.

To form the content clause, a subordinator "that" is used.

The subordinator can be omitted, and then you get

> I expect he will play.

But "I expect him will play" is incorrect.  In this construction "he" is the subject of "will play" and has the subject form "he", not "him".

So in your example, the form in the book is natural, but it could also be written:

> I don't expect them to be waiting for me.

> I don't expect that they will be waiting for me.

> I don't expect they will be waiting for me.

The expectation is about a future event, so a future tense is used in the content clause.

It is also possible to write about present expectations of a past event:

> I expect that he played.

(You can understand this as "I expect that I will learn that he played")

or present and  ongoing:

> I expect that he is playing.

But in your situation "I don't expect that they were waiting for me" is grammatically correct but the meaning is rather odd.  (it means something like "I do not expect that I will learn that they had been waiting for me".)

Comment: The OP clearly has some problems with English verb tenses, so I think it's worth pointing out that we can also combine Present Tense ***expect*** with a *Past* event, if the speaker doesn't yet know the details of that past event: *I **don't** expect [that] they **waited** for me*. Or Present; *I don't expect **they're waiting** for me*.

Comment: Fixed.  And I've changed my mind... the subordinator "that" can be omitted.

Comment: I can hardly deny you an upvote after all those improvements! To be honest, I didn't actually notice that you'd said that that "that" *can't* be omitted. On purely stylistic grounds I'm sure some people would very much like to omit at least *one* of those three consecutive ***that***'s in my preceding sentence - but unless I'm mistaken, syntactically it's *always* valid to include OR omit "that" used as a subordinator in such contexts.